# Azure DevOps Copy Task to copy particular subfolder and files inside it

Tags: azure-devops

I have nested folder structure and I just want to copy specific folder and files under it
I need help to understand copy task content structure

Here is folder structure

```
Scripts
  Bin
   obj
     Application
       Test
        App
         file1
         file2
```

I want to copy Just the app folder and files under it

```
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
     SourceFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/Scripts'
     Contents: '**\app\**'
     TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/Dev'
```

Comment: Hi megha, any update on this question, have you checked my answer, does my answer answered your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your YAML definition only works in windows agent.

Please make sure the charactor are same:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  # vmImage: windows-latest
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
- name: system.debug
  value: true
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Scripts'
    Contents: |
      **/App/**
    TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/targetfolder'
    flattenFolders: true
- script: |
    cd targetfolder
    dir
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

'App', not 'app'. And you need 'flattenFolders' section as 'true'.

Refer to this official document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml